# In SSR 2008 R2 how do you filter a tablix using a dynamic IN comparison?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a tablix and want to filter using the IN conditional. The problem is SSRS is giving a byte to string comparison error. I know I can modify the parameter and SQL to make this happen but I am using the SQL statement in more than one place. I really just want to filter it in one place but not another.

I want to say,

```
MyField
IN
If Parameter!xyz.Value = True Then "0,1" 
Else "0,1,2"
```

This will pass a dynamic value into the IN clause.

If I plug the 0,1 directly into the filter value it works.

I have tried,

```
Split("0,1", ",") <- Byte error
"0,1" OR "0" <- Byte error
```

I guess a second question here is what is SSRS converting the 0,1 into when I plug it directly into the filter value?

Answer (score 0):

Some people claim multi-value integers work correctly but I have never got it to work for me. Are you setting the Filter type to Text?

For what you want, I just use INSTR:

**Expression**:

```
=IIF(INSTR(IIF(Parameter!xyz.Value, "0,1", "0,1,2"), CSTR(MyField)) > 0 , 1, 0)
```

**Type**: Integer

**Operator**: =

**Value**: 1

Comment: It is text on the filter.

Comment: In theory, it should work using TEXT but I could never get it to. That's why I usually end up doing a work around like the INST expression.